# Knex.js parameter binding with Oracle partitions

Tags: oracle, knex.js

TL;DR; Is there any way to tell knex.js to not use parameter binding? Instead inject the value into the raw query?

We are currently using knex.js in a Node.js environment with Oracle as our database. We have run into a case with poor query performance and have narrowed it down to the parameter binding on a partitioned table.

Our table is partitioned on a `CREATE_DATE` column and knex.js is generating a query that looks something like this:

```
select col1, col2 from my_table where create_date >= ? and create_date < ?
```

If I understand the Oracle documentation, and based on some testing, Oracle is using dynamic pruning in this case and is causing some pretty poor performance for us. If I manually re-run the query like this it is very fast:

```
select col1, col2 from my_table where create_date >= to_date('2020-05-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and create_date < to_date('2020-05-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Running an `explain plan` on both of those queries gives vastly different performance results. The first one has a much higher cost than the second.

Is there any way to tell knex.js to use a literal value rather than use parameter binding?

Answer (score 0):

As `Knex` is a query builder, it has a way to pass [raw query](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw), or part of it.

```js
knex('my_table')
  .columns('col1', 'col2')
  .whereRaw("create_date >= to_date('2020-05-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')")
  .whereRaw("create_date < to_date('2020-05-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')");
```

Comment: This syntax still uses parameter binding. If you run `toSQL()` on your example the `bindings` array is populated with the two date values.

Comment: Do you think that these bindings are slowing your query? anyway, i've updated the answer

Comment: Yes, the bindings are absolutely slowing the query down because `create_date` is a partitioned column and Oracle is using dynamic pruning to fetch results. Your updated answer, while technically doesn't use binding, is not quite what I'm looking for. We are still dynamically building the query and I was hoping there was a flag or trick to tell knex to *not* bind. Similar to what sequelize does with replacements: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements

Comment: `> We are still dynamically building the query and I was hoping there was a flag or trick to tell knex to not bind.` Does oracledb driver has an option which can be used to tell to not to use bindings? If there is then knex should support query basis extra options that can be passed to the driver when query is done. http://knexjs.org/#Builder-options